# How can I add a calender to my Android tablet?

Tags: calendar

How can I add a calender to my Android tablet? In Settings>Accounts& Synch I can only create Exchange account. There is no option to create any calendar. I do not have android market, google calender, gmail android apps. I standard calendar pre-installed - but I can do nothing because I have no calendars to save events. How to fix it?

Answer (score 2):

Seems like you have an Android tablet without the Google APIs. This are devices that use Android but without a Google branding ("with Google (TM)") and Google Services Framework (Google API) to avoid paying fees to Google.
Android itself is open-source so every manufacture can use it without charge on their devices, **but if they want to have the Google Services like Market, Maps, Navigation, Google Calendar and so an, they have to pay a license fee to Google.** You can recognize devices with Google Services based on the "with Google (TM)" branding on the back of the device.

AFAIK there a ways to install the Google API when you have root on your device.

Comment: What do you mean by "avoid paying fees to Google"

Comment: @roxan I have updated my answer

Comment: Thanks I didn't know about that. Do you have some reading material regarding the license fee?